# iOS development license and itunes connect

Tags: ios, licensing, app-store-connect

New to iOS development and everything with the license is driving me nuts. So i got a few questions.

I have a developer account but not a license yet. If i buy a iOS developer license for $99, that license is then stuck to my account?

Can one developer account have multiple iTunes Connect accounts or is it stuck to one?

Before i started to read up on stuff my account got added to a company's iTunes Connect account. If i then buy a license would i be stuck to just develop to that company or is it possible to change?

I want to develop for my self and also one specific company. Can i use the same licence or do i need two?

Can you have multiple licenses/certifications or whatever its called in Xcode?

Is the iOS Developer Program both for development and distribution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, if you buy a $99 developer license, then that license is then associated to an Apple ID for the duration of your subscription.

2) An iTunes Connect account is limited to one per Apple ID & email address, but your "regular" login for developer.apple.com can be part of more than one team, or developer license.

3) You can either contact Apple to have them revoke your affiliation to the company's developer account, or use it to register for your own - however, my experience with this has only been for one $99 account and with one $299 enterprise account, but I imagine they'd work with two normal accounts.

4) Technically you could use the existing license, which is that of the company you are already with - but I would strongly recommend getting your own to avoid any possible conflicts that may arise between you and them in the future.

5) Yes, the Organizer within Xcode can handle multiple developers, licenses and the full range of provisioning profiles.

6) Yes, you can create development and distribution provisioning profiles with either type of iOS developer account.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Since i have not yet gotten the license i could create a new account. But i would rather keep my old since got other stuff associated with it.